# TFLite model conversion shows warning and using the converted model with interpreter crashes python kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have a tensorflow keras model which has the following architecture:

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 199)]             0         
                                                                 
 token_and_position_embeddin  (None, 199, 256)         2611456   
 g_2 (TokenAndPositionEmbedd                                     
 ing)                                                            
                                                                 
 lstm_4 (LSTM)               (None, 199, 150)          244200    
                                                                 
 lstm_5 (LSTM)               (None, 150)               180600    
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10001)             1510151   
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 4,546,407
Trainable params: 4,546,407
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I am trying to convert it to tflite in this way:

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(str(model_saved_dir))
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float16]
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
# Save the model.
with open(model_home / 'model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

During conversion it shows the following warnings:

```
2022-04-12 20:17:23.584937: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:301] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 329307 microseconds.
2022-04-12 20:17:23.771051: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:237] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
2022-04-12 20:17:23.983377: W tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/flatbuffer_export.cc:1892] TFLite interpreter needs to link Flex delegate in order to run the model since it contains the following Select TFop(s):
Flex ops: FlexTensorListFromTensor, FlexTensorListGetItem, FlexTensorListReserve, FlexTensorListSetItem, FlexTensorListStack
Details:
    tf.TensorListFromTensor(tensor<199x?x256xf32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x256xf32>>>) : {device = ""}
    tf.TensorListFromTensor(tensor<?x?x150xf32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x150xf32>>>) : {device = ""}
    tf.TensorListGetItem(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x150xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> (tensor<?x150xf32>) : {device = ""}
    tf.TensorListGetItem(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x256xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> (tensor<?x256xf32>) : {device = ""}
    tf.TensorListReserve(tensor<2xi32>, tensor<i32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x150xf32>>>) : {device = ""}
    tf.TensorListSetItem(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x150xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<?x150xf32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x150xf32>>>) : {device = ""}
    tf.TensorListStack(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x150xf32>>>, tensor<2xi32>) -> (tensor<?x?x150xf32>) : {device = "", num_elements = -1 : i64}
See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select
WARNING:absl:Buffer deduplication procedure will be skipped when flatbuffer library is not properly loaded
```

But the file is created after this and when trying to use this model in this way:

```py
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=str(model_home / 'model.tflite'))
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]

# dummy input
ip = [[0 for _ in range(198)] + [1]]
ip = np.array(ip, dtype=np.int32)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, ip)
interpreter.invoke()
predictions = interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
print(predictions)
```

my jupyter notebook kernel dies and python program crashes. My tensorflow version is '2.8.0' and python version is '3.8.10'. When I try to use the model from Android studio it also crashes showing error `ByteBuffer is not a valid FlatBuffer model`.

Comment: 1) Conversion warning:

The warning is not a problem, it is just telling you that you will need to use runtime with TF SELECT (Flex) to be able to run this model - more details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select).

2) Runtime:

Python runtime should have Flex support by default, can you share the stack trace or the file so we can guide.

For the Java runtime, can you share how you loaded the model and ran it.

Comment: I have solved the problem by specifying input and output size when converting the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem of crashing python kernel and also crashing when loading in Android Studio by adding input and output size to the model signature before converting the model:

```py
run_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
# This is important, let's fix the input size.
BATCH_SIZE = 1
INPUT_SIZE = 199
concrete_func = run_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec([BATCH_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE], model.inputs[0].dtype))

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Comment: What's concrete_func ? your code has mistake?